# asp.net web api self hosting : what does the threading model look like?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm using self hosting asp.net web api from a WPF appliaction that serves as a server.
I'm wondering what the scaling will be like for many clients when self hosted, does the web api manage a thread pool & recycle those? Or is it single threaded by default? Does it use 1 thread per call or does it have a limit etc etc.
Any information on this would be great as well as any information on the configurability of the threading behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the threadpool and manages it. There can be multiple threads involved in a single call.  If you are expecting fairly high concurrency of requests, then I would recommend looking into using Owin to host your WebApi.

Comment: I'm already self hosting it, i don't want to add another component (beside it's really not a web <>web thing, it's just a wpf server interface, with WPF clients, not a 2 tier server system i'm implementing).

Comment: I'm not expecting high load, but i definately want multiple requests running concurrently on multiple threads, is there any configurability for this directly in the self hosted web api? I couldn't find much info beyond the basic tutorial level stuff on web api.

Comment: @RonanThibaudau  As long as you don't want too many concurrent requests, it will work out of the box.  Setting ThreadPool.SetMinThreads() helps it scale but I've still run into issues.

Comment: So no need to touch configuration (nothing like wcf's concurrency mode or something similar to tweak ?)